# node http server not listening

Tags: node.js, windows, express

For some reason my express node.js server won't start anymore. Usually I just run the `npm start` command in my application folder and the server will start listening. now it is stuck at `> node ./bin/www`.

```
> myapp@0.0.0 start C:\Users\...\first-app
> node ./bin/www
```

I did not change anything significant, just restarted the server and it did not work anymore. This already happened before and I reinstalled express and then it would work again. I just cant reinstall express all the time.

Also changed ports, same result.

Comment: It's alright if it stuck at **node ./bin/www** without any error. It means the server is stated and listen for request. Did you try to send any request?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 'website not available error'. I have an eventlistener .on('listening') that usually prints debug('Listening on ' + address); into the console when it is working.

Comment: I restarted my pc again and now the listener is still not firing, but the webpage is loading. So I guess your answer is right. Kinda curious why the listener is not working anymore though.